# No option to choose Left/Right click select in the 2.8 Preferences

Tags: customization, selection-tools

I want to switch to right click but, there is no option to do that in the User Preferences. I should be located at the top of the *Keymap* section.

[image: keymap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have been using an older version of 2.8 with a custom keymap prior. Even through reinstalled, the custom keymap was kept.

The way <sup>hopefully not</sup> to get the Preferences Panel at the top of the Keymaps is to switch to a default keymap like *Blender* which strangely also has a few of the changed keys which were in the custom keymap.<sup>very strange</sup>

[image: keymap settings]